# Ошибка сборки VS2013 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Появилась ошибка со следующим текстом при сборке проекта(.NET) на C#.

> 1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Frgo.SignatureTools, Конфигурация: Debug x86 ------
>   1>EXEC : error : Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
>   1>

Я использую .tt файлы для генерации AssemblyInfo.cs. Все работало хорошо пока я не поставил VS2015.Но и потом все было хорошо, пока я не принял решения опять перейти на VS2013. И вот тут появилась эта ошибка(на англоязычном форуме нашел вот такую [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847855/t4-text-transformations-in-vs2013-and-vs2015)). Ответ вроде понятен. Но я не знаю, как я могу изменить именно настройку сборки чтобы прописать не Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0 а Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interface.11.0(например)?

Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо.

Comment: Помогла переустановка VS2013.

Comment: Мажем научу её за 4 дня разговаривать?